# How to pass argument to HyperLinkedIdentityField's view_name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework and have created a serializer class as

```
class ForumTopicListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    threadUrl = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
            view_name = 'forum-api:thread_list_forum_topic'
        )
    class Meta:
        model = ForumTopic
        fields =[
        'id',
        'title',
        'threadUrl'
       ]
```

I Have a HyperLinkedIDentityField and the view there is forum-api:thread_list_forum_topic but the problem is that this view requires an argument to be passed.

Its url is as

```
url(r'thread/topic/(?P<forumTopic>[0-9]+)/$',  ThreadListForumTopicAPIView.as_view(), name = 'thread_list_forum_topic'),
```

So how do i pass the argument of the forumTopic is the HyperLinkedIdentityField?

Comment: Can you try in this way?.                                                                    threadUrl = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name=forum-api:thread_list_forum_topic', lookup_field='forumTopic')

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to get as your URL args? In `views.py` or in your `serializers.py`? If you are in `views.py` here is a snippet:

```
from rest_framework import generics
class ThreadListForumTopicAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = serializers.ForumTopicListSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    forumTopic = self.kwargs["forumTopic"]
```

The URL parameters are set in `self.kwargs` of the view class. The code above is just snippet, you'll obviously have to finish it out to return the query set.

And here's the supporting documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url

Comment: I am trying to get them in serializers.py and as in my question            threadUrl = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
            view_name = 'forum-api:thread_list_forum_topic'
        )
The view_name is the url of the view so i want to be able to pass the url kwargs here.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood your original question. Take a look at the docs, I think you'll need to set either `lookup_field` or `lookup_url_kwargs`: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield